# Batch: Returning a value from a SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: string, shell, batch-file, console, delayedvariableexpansion

I wonder why this code does not work as expected:

```
@ECHO off
SET S1=HELLO

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET S2=!S1! WORLD^^!
ECHO !S2!
ENDLOCAL & SET S1=!S2!

ECHO %S1%
PAUSE
```

Output:

```
HELLO WORLD!
!S2!
```

Expected output:

```
HELLO WORLD!
HELLO WORLD!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works as expected.
The delayed expansion will expand variables at execution time, not parse time, so it interpret your line `ENDLOCAL & SET S1=!S2!` as
`endlocal`
But at the part of `SET S1=!S2!` the delayed expansion is off so it can't be expanded anymore.

In your case you could use
`ENDLOCAL & SET S1=%S2%`

As the exclamation mark is S2 is "safe", as the delayed exp. is off at the moment of execution.

But an always secure returning is a bit more complicated.
We discussed it at [Dostips: Return ANY string across ENDLOCAL boundry](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7446)