# Batch - Get value of local with delayed expansion

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

In the following code I create some pseudo array (representing pairs) and call a routine which gets the name of the pseudo array and its size as parameter values. In the routine I want to access each array element in a loop. To my knowledge the only possibility to access the array values is to use delayed expansion which would not be problem if i could get back the value of the delayed expansion local.

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set pairs[0]="a" "b"
        set pairs[1]="c" "d"
        set pairs[2]="e" "f"
        set pairNumber=3

        call :my_routine pairs %pairNumber%
    ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0

:my_routine
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set myPairs=%1
        set /a maxCount=%2-1

        for /l %%c in (0,1,%maxCount%) do (
            set "currentPair="
            SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
                call set "pair=%%!myPairs![%%c]%%"
                REM setting the value works:
                REM echo !pair!
            ENDLOCAL & set "currentPair=%pair%"
            echo %currentPair%
        )
    ENDLOCAL
exit /b 0
```

Expected Output:

```
"a" "b"
"c" "d"
"e" "f"
```

The crucial part is `& set currentPair=%pair%`. To my understanding the `%pair%` value is not set because of using delayed expansion when setting it.

The question is about getting the value back NOT about telling me that I could do stuff in the local itself. This is something i would consider if there is no way to get the value back.

I also took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9408953/5233188) very similiar question but the solution does not work for me.

So...

How do i get the value out of the inner local so that `currentPair` gets the value of `pair`?

Comment: You've had enough help and advice thus far to know that the recommended syntax for setting variables is `Set "Variable=Value"` and if that variable is being undefined/emptied `Set "Variable="`. _There's a good reason why it is recommended!_

Comment: @Compo Well, I know that it is possible to use the `Set "Variable=Value"` although i still don't know why it is recommended... But i edited with the _right_ way anyway. So what is the good reason?

Comment: @goulashsoup Please read the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) There is explained in detail why `Set "Variable=Value"` is recommended as long as __command extensions__ are enabled as by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of passing a variable value beyond the `endlocal` barrier relies on the fact that it is not placed within a block of code, but you placed the line `endlocal & set "currentPair=%pair%"` within a `for /L` loop.

You can use a `for /F` loop instead, like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%E in (""!pair!"") do (
    endlocal
    set "currentPair=%%~E"
)
```

The outer pair of quotes around `!pair!` tells `for /F` that it is a literal string; the inner pair is part of that string, which is then removed by the `~` modifier in `%%~E`. The purpose of this is to ensure that the loop always iterates once (even when `!pair!` is empty), and so `endlocal` becomes executed.

This also works in another block of code like your `for /L` loop.

Of course the line `echo %currentPair%` does not return the correct string, but you could place `echo(%%~E` within the `for /F` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm sure this will not be what you wanted*; but based upon limited information you've provided, and the known string content, there is no need to be setting unnecessary variables or enabling and disabling delayed expansion within the `For /L` loop.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "pairs[0]="a" "b""
Set "pairs[1]="c" "d""
Set "pairs[2]="e" "f""
Set "pairNumber=2"

Call :my_routine pairs %pairNumber% currentPair

Exit /B 0

    :my_routine
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    For /L %%A In (0,1,%2) Do Set "%3=!%1[%%A]!" & Echo !%3!

    Pause

    Exit /B 0
```

*You can optionally change `Echo !%3!`to `Set %3` if required
Each `SetLocal` will `EndLocal` with their respective `Exit`*